# Why returning pointer to an object only work sometime?

Tags: c++, c++11

I had a bug which is resolved recently but I want to understand why. I have a cmake project using c++11.

This works on mac osx but not on ubuntu. It returns null on ubuntu.

```
obj *getPointer(){
  obj test = obj(1,2,3);
  return &test;
}
```

This works on both:

```
obj *getPointer(){
  obj* ptr;
  obj test = obj(1,2,3);
  ptr = &test
  return &ptr;
}
```

Comment: You should enable warning as error and see it not compiling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both of your instances invoke undefined behaviour (UB), as you are returning the address of a local object `obj test` with [automatic storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) which is being destroyed at the exit from the function so you end up with a dangling pointer. It just "happens" to work, but anything can happen, so you should avoid UB at all costs!

To understand why it happens to work, that's because probably at the exit from the function the function's stack is not yet reclaimed by the OS, so the dangling pointer happens to point to the same data.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/3093378) to [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) offers one of the best explanations I've ever seen about dangling pointers.

Comment: What is the right way to do it? Should I pass the test obj from caller function like main? or should I create object with new key and delete it when everything is done in another function?

Comment: @Nick You should create it with `new` and release it with `delete`. Or better, use [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

Comment: @Nick I think you should return it by value and let the compiler elide the copy.

Comment: Don't use `new`, do't use smart pointers, just return the object. `obj GetPointer() { ... return test; }`. Simple enough, and let the compiler make it efficient.

Comment: make sense but my function does not guarantee return object imagine this function calls several times and one of them is give the object so for the other cases I return nullptr

Comment: actually not returning pointer to a local variable causes UB only using dereferenced value :)

Comment: @W.F. True, indeed.

Comment: @Nick Relevant: [What can happen when you return a pointer to a local object.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6fdb31cb4054b7ab)  Note that even though the return value from the second call to `retIntPtr()` is discarded, the object from the first call still changed.  Once the function returns, all of the memory that it used was freed, including the object that was allocated.

Comment: @Nick If you need to return a pointer, you should probably be using `new` and `delete`, or a smart pointer, like vsoftco said.  [You won't run into that problem.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/049a189ffde2b128)